# Invalid X-Frame-Options header in iframe-embedded Fusion Tables map

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm seeing this in the Chrome javascript console when loading a FT map embedded in an iframe:

Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col4%3E%3E0+f…%3E0+%3D+'Y'&h=false&lat=40.0&lng=-100.0&z=4&t=1&l=col4%3E%3E0&y=2&tmplt=3': '' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

The page is here: http://new.oto-usa.org/wordpress/locations/

Anybody know what's up with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here. I haven't used embedviz.  But you have a single quote inside your single quote iframe src.  Look for +'Y'

Comment: That seems to be an artifact of the error reporting system. Here's the iframe source copied straight off my page: `<iframe width="850px" height="600px" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col4%3E%3E0+from+1JJHwwJLW1CqrG3PZv3kMBrRJio-5f_28g_rJrYU+where+col7%3E%3E0+%3D+&#39;Y&#39;&amp;h=false&amp;lat=40.0&amp;lng=-100.0&amp;z=4&amp;t=1&amp;l=col4%3E%3E0&amp;y=2&amp;tmplt=3"></iframe>`